# RES folder not linked into .apk -> "probl.em parsing the package"

Tags: android, android-resources

For some strange reason, the "res" folder is never linked into my apps when exporting them - as a result, when I try  to install these apk's, I get the well-known "there was a problem parsing the package" error message.

During export, no error messages are displayed... :/

**Edit:** *please note that I am NOT referring to the often described issue of an actual device OS version mismatch!* The problem is that -for some reason I don't know- the exported APK (which is actually a .zip file as we know) does not contain the 'res' subfolder as usual, only the META-INF subfolder. Proguard is disabled to rule that out as a possible cause. So for some reason, the app's resources are not linked into the target .apk, and the package really IS invalid. Interestingly enough, the "debug" version to be run on the local virtual device is compiled just fine and contains the "res" subfolder.
*The same source code creates a correct .apk package on another computer.* So the problem seems to be in the ADT/Eclipse setup?

Answer (score 0):

There is a parsing problem error comes only when you have SDK version mismatch error. lets suppose if my minSDK version in manifest is 14 and i am trying to install application on 2.2 device which have sdk version 8 then it will give me parsing error. Please provide your manifest file.

Comment: But you must be sure that your code is compatible with lower Android versions. I.e.: If you're using fragments and didn't include the support library, what happens on the older device?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this isn't my problem. I've edited the problem description above to provide more details. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

There are some alternative to resolve this issue ,

**Case 1:**

- Go to device  Settings(icon) menu
- Security
- Device administration
- Unknown sources
- Check mark Unknown sources
- Now try to install the .apk file.Hope it will help

**Case 2:**

If the device Android OS version is not compatible with the .apk file
Like .apk file is build in minimum SDK version 15,and SDK target 17(ICS) and you have device version 2.3 (gingerbread) or any other.

We can change build version any time through Manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> // or as per your requirements
```

Other thing is that your device is not compatible for your app. like you have use some additional library or some Hardware resources which is not applicable to run on your device so in that case you can get this issue.

While you update your APK in market that will first check device compatibility & then allow to install otherwise your app will not visible for your device.

Comment: But you must be sure that your code is compatible with lower Android versions. I.e.: If you're using fragments and didn't include the support library, what happens on the older device?

Comment: @ArtooDetoo Yes , that i have mentation min sdk version,

Comment: It's not enough. If your JAVA code requires HIGHER API levels and you only have a LOWER API device, it won't work. minSdkVersion doesn't add the higher software layer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this isn't my problem. I've edited the problem description above to provide more details. Sorry for the confusion!